# How do I get the record in Rails that I just updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Active Record returns the record on `create` but not `update`, it only returns true. Is there a way to get this record or do I have to find it again? This is the current behavior:

```
some_model_instance.create(params) => Active Record Obj
some_model_instance.update(params) => True
```

Comment: Show some code, please.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the record in `some_model_instance`. Depending on the nature of your update, it will usually reflect the changes. Sometimes there are side-effects to updating (depending on your code, or things outside your control, like database triggers). If you want to be sure that `some_model_instance` represents the true state, reload it:

```
some_model_instance.reload
```